# Can i share iOS debug application using TestFairy without having Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, flutter, testfairy

I am an Android developer and I don't really know much about how this iOS building app works.

I currently develop a Flutter application and I share it with my coworkers using TestFairy. So far I share only Android build but we need to share an iOS version now too. Is there a simple and free way to do this? If not with TestFairy maybe with a different tool?

Edit: By free I mean without having to pay for Apple Developer account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is no, there is no way to do this without Apple Developer account.

Maybe you can extract some IPA file from debugging build and install it on an iPhone which has jailbreak, but I think this is not what you looking for.

Comment: Too bad, but I expected that... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. Here is the [link](https://docs.testfairy.com/App_Distribution/Distributing_Your_Apps.html), it clearly says you will need enterprise account for distribution through TestFairy

Comment: Too bad, but I expected that... Thanks!

Comment: You can use either Ad Hoc certificate ($99/year) or Enterprise certificate ($299/year). TestFairy works with both for distribution.